# How to make column take up remaining space

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this simple bootstrap content and I wanted to make the second column fill up the space

**Code**

```
<div id="app">   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> 
    </nav>  
    <div class="content">   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Featured</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">First Column</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Curabitur accumsan turpis pharetra accumsan turpis pharetra augue tincidunt blandit. Quisque condimentum maximusaugue tincidunt blandit. Quisque condimentum maximus mi, sit amet commodo arcu rutrum id. Proin pretium urna vel cursus venenatis. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam mattis sem rhoncus lacus dapibus facilisis. Donec at dignissim dui. Ut et neque nisl.Curabitur accumsan turpis pharetra accumsan turpis pharetra augue tincidunt blandit. Quisque condimentum maximusaugue tincidunt blandit. Quisque condimentum maximus mi, sit amet commodo arcu rutrum id. Proin pretium urna vel cursus venenatis. Suspendisse potenti</p>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h5 class="card-header">Featured</h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Second Column needs to take up the remaining space</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">additional content.</p>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQPdLj/

So how do I make it without using a specific height for second column? The first column can take up any space and the other needs to fill it even if the content is less. I tried `flex-grow` and `flex-fill` but didn't work for me.

Comment: The columns are the same height, but the cards are not. You could add `h-100` to the cards to make them fill the column height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the column flex and make the card flex-grow:1:

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
}
.card {  
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: #eff2fb;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQyvEE)

Comment: @skyline33 accept jakub's answer instead - it uses the proper bootstrap classes

Comment: Pete I like to keep the html clean and always avoid inline styles or whatever they are called since I will be using a lot of columns it will be headache to put "d-flex align-items-stretch" to every column. I will be using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a ready bootstrap solution.

Add `d-flex align-items-stretch` classes to elements having `col-sm-6`.

```
<div class="content">   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                // ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                // ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See working code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQPyWY

Answer (score 0):

This also work add class "d-flex align-items-stretch" both column.